# Firebase matching substring

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the JSON structure above
[image]

I want to get the list of vehicles where their ids ends with "123"

I had tried to use Query.endAt() method but i'm not sure if i'm using it right or it shouldn't give the required output

```
Query vehiclesRef;
vehiclesRef = db.getReference("vehicles").orderByKey().endAt("\uf8ff123");
```

Comment: Please add the code you have already tried and explain what issues you are having. BTW this does not look like a reasonable JSON Structure. I would expect "vehicles" to be an array.

Comment: Question edited, Barns.

Comment: what output is it giving?

Comment: It makes no difference, it returns the same array.

Comment: what is `query`? It should return childs of the key ending with 123. To test it add it with a listener and retrieve one child under a key and see if you get all children under those keys or only children under keys that end with 123

Comment: query is the variable which in this case "123", question edited anyway.
I've already added it with a listener and tested it with equalTo() method and returning the right value but only when i have the whole key, i just want to match the substring at the end of the key.

Comment: @MohamedM.AbdElHafiz use it with `_`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Database queries can only perform prefix matches, so strings *starting* with a specific string or starting with a range of string. It is not possible to query for strings *ending* with a specific value, nor those ending with a range of values.

If you really want to do this within Firebase, consider also storing the reversed strings in the database:

```
"321_1_0"
"321_3_0"
"654_52_0"
```

Then you can query for strings starting with `321` with

```
vehiclesQuery = db.getReference("vehicles").orderByKey().startAt("321").endAt("321\uf8ff");
```