# Efficient way to query sql like in firebase

Tags: firebase

What's the updated and effient way to query sql like in firebase? I've search in forums and they say I should query all the documents then just do a javascript match function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Database in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222347/firebase-database-in-sql)

Comment: See Doug's answer. Additionally, you may get a more specific answer if you can update your question with the query you're trying to do. Include a description of the query, what your Firebase structure looks like and what the desired outcome is.

Answer (score 2):

Neither database provided by Firebase (Realtime Database and Firestore) have support for LIKE queries.  **This is not going to change any time soon, as these types of queries do not scale with the sort of indexes provided by these database.**

You can do string prefix queries, which is similar to "WHERE field LIKE foo%", but that's all you get.

For Realtime Database, see:

- [Firebase matching substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47858505/firebase-matching-substring)
- [How to perform sql "LIKE" operation on firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase)
- [Firebase query - Find item with child that contains string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589092/firebase-query-find-item-with-child-that-contains-string)

For Firestore, see:

- [Google Firestore: Query on substring of a property value (text search)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568142/google-firestore-query-on-substring-of-a-property-value-text-search)
- [Firestore Comparison Operators - contains, does not contain, starts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47195122/firestore-comparison-operators-contains-does-not-contain-starts-with)
- [Is there a way to search sub string at Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115422/is-there-a-way-to-search-sub-string-at-firestore)